# There are exactly $\binom{r}{k}\binom{n-1}{n-r+k}$ solutions of $\sum_{i = 1}^{r} x_i = n$, for which exactly $k$ of $x_i = 0$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

This is an exercise taken from *A First Course in Probability (8e)* by Sheldon Ross (p.20).

Note that in this problem all $x_i$ are nonnegative integer.

I try to argue that having $k$ of $x_i = 0$, the equation is equivalent to having the other $r - k$ of $x_i > 0$ summing up to $n$, which has exactly $\binom{n - 1}{r - k - 1}$ distinct solutions, as the book says at p.13:

> **Proposition 6.1** There are $\binom{n - 1}{r - 1}$ distinct positive integer-valued vectors $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_r)$ satisfying the equation:
> $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r = n,\ x_i > 0,\ i = 1, \dots, r$$

However, the exercise says the number of solutions is $\binom{r}{k}\binom{n-1}{n-r+k}$. Why am I wrong?

**Edit 1**: I now realise where the $\binom{r}{k}$ comes, but even so my solution $\binom{r}{k}\binom{n - 1}{r - k - 1}$ still differs from the correct one.

Comment: You are correct that there are $\binom{n-1}{r-k-1}$ solutions *once you have chosen which of the $x_i$'s are $0$*. There are $\binom rk$ possible choices for these, so you have to multiply your answer by $\binom rk$. (Note that $\binom{n-1}{r-k-1}=\binom{n-1}{n-r+k}$.)

Comment: @nejimban Thank you, I understand it now, but I think you make a typo, it should be multiplied by $\binom{r}{k}$ instead of $\binom{k}{r}$?

Comment: The assertion is simply a disguised form of Stars and Bars theory, focusing on $$x_1 + \cdots + x_j = n ~: ~x_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}, ~i \in \{1,2,\cdots,j\}.$$  The change of variable $y_i = x_i - 1$ leads to $$y_1 + \cdots + y_j = (n-j) ~: ~y_i \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}},$$ which has $~\displaystyle \binom{[n-j] + [j-1]}{j-1}~$ solutions.

Comment: @luma Yes it was a typo :)